# How to emit client event over web sockets on page load in Laravel and VueJs?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, websocket

Following the documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#client-events, I have set up web sockets successfully, everything works fine using the following code in Vue.Js component to emit client event:

```
updated() {
    // The event is not being emitted on page load.
    Echo.private('chat').whisper('typing', dataObject });
},
mounted() {
    // The event is not being emitted on page load.
    Echo.private('chat').whisper('typing', dataObject });
},
created() {
    // The event is not being emitted on page load.
    Echo.private('chat').whisper('typing', dataObject });
},
methods: {
    submit() { // Event will only be emitted when this `submit()` method is being called by an input field event like `@input`, `@change` etc.
        Echo.private('chat').whisper('typing', dataObject });
    }
}
```

I would like to emit event on the client side on the moment the page is loaded because I have default avialable data object.

I have tried the above code in Vue.Js lifecycle hooks e.g. `created`, `mounted` and `updated`. But that event cannot be emited on page load.

How can I emit client event over the web sockets on page load in Laravel and Vue.Js?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? I assume you're calling `submit()` somewhere? Because that code alone does nothing. To use it, you would add `this.submit()` in your `mounted` (afaik), or move the `Echo....` command there.

Comment: I am not getting any error. The event is just not being emitted on page load. I skip the html template. The `submit()` function can be called with any input event like `@input` or @change`. That works fine. Now I need to emit/broadcast event on page load. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Can you do some basic debugging? Does *anything* you put in `mounted` get called? If not, there's your problem, and it is entirely unrelated to using Laravel's `Echo`.

Comment: In general, anything in VueJs lifecycle hooks will be executed, including `mounted`. That is not the problem. The problem is that event cannot be emitted during execution process in those hooks. Maybe because client first needs to connect to the websocket and to subscribe. I am not sure. But the solution is to put `Echo...` in the `setTimeout()` to delay it a little bit. And it works well in both `created` or `mounted`.